# Counterexamples to the Ahlfors measure conjecture in higher dimensions

Tags: cv.complex-variables, ergodic-theory, hyperbolic-geometry

Let $\Gamma<SO(3,1)$ be a finitely generated, discrete group of isometries of $\mathbb H^3$. By work of Agol, Calegari, Canary, and Gabai, the limit set of $\Gamma$ is either the entire sphere $S^2\cong \partial \mathbb H^3$, or has zero area. (This result had first been conjectured by Ahlfors, hence the name.)

Are there any known counterexamples to the corresponding result for higher dimensions? What if we add the tameness restriction that $\mathbb{H^n}/\Gamma$ has a manifold compactification?

Comment: Terra incognita....

Comment: See the discussion at the end of section 10.1 of [M. Kapovich, Kleinian groups in higher dimensions. In "Geometry and Dynamics of Groups and Spaces. In memory of Alexander Reznikov'', M.Kapranov et al (eds). Birkhauser, Progress in Mathematics, Vol. 265, 2007, p. 485-562], https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~kapovich/EPR/klein.pdf. It mentions a complex hyperbolic counterexample.

Comment: @IgorBelegradek: +1 for a reference, but, no, you are mistaken.

Comment: @MoisheKohan: Oops, I did not read the body question carefully. The complex hyperbolic counterexample is to ergodicity, not the claim that the limit set is the whole sphere at infinity.